# SqlAlchemy declarative architecture supporting queries for both base class and subclass?

Tags: sqlalchemy, polymorphism, subclass

I have an SqlAlchemy declarative base class from which more complex classes are derived but for which I also use and will query for instances that are "plain" instances of the base class. My current approach doesn't quite sit right with me; I feel like I'm missing a possible simpler approach.

What I have now, as below, is a base class (e.g., `GenericFoo`) from which I derive what outside the SqlAlchemy context would be a redundant "wrapper" class (`SpecificFoo`) that does nothing but put instances in a different table, so that I can query that table for the "plain" instances. The more complex subclass is a straightforward extension as shown below.

I guess this works, but it feels... wasteful to add a separate table for this. An alternative would to filter in some way a `GenericFoo` query to grab only "plain" instances that have no corresponding entry in the `ChildOfFoo` table, but that feels a little hacky. This seems like a fairly typical situation, but I haven't found anything describing a standard approach to this. Is there one?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class GenericFoo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'generic_foo'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'generic_foo'}

    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

# This table only exists to query for things that aren't ChildOfFoo.
class SpecificFoo(GenericFoo):
    __tablename__ = 'specific_foo'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'specific_foo'}

class ChildOfFoo(GenericFoo):
    __tablename__ = 'child_of_foo'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child_of_foo'}

    def __init__(self, name, color, age):
        super(ChildOfFoo, self).__init__(name, color)
        self.age = age
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like something along these lines, using `of_type`, is close, although in my use case I'm not trying to `join` anything:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance_loading.html#referring-to-specific-subtypes-on-relationships

Comment: Did you have a look into this part of the documentation: [Mixin and Custom Base Classes] (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html)

Comment: @rfkortekaas, my first pass at using Mixins was only able to eliminate the "extra" table, but I can't seem to get the inherited base class Foreign Keys right, without having queries into the base class table return child class instances. What I want is a clean way to query "just plain base class" instances and not have to check each to see whether it's base class or a child class. Not sure I'm not missing something that can work with the Mixin approach. (I should write up an example to explain where I'm stuck.)

Comment: Can you please do that as to me it's not totally clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rfkortekaas OK, I see what was confusing me. The idea that there would still be a subclass relationship in the ORM classes was somehow stuck in my head. Now that I see that that isn't how it's structured it's easy to do it with a couple of plain python Mixin classes.